# latex equation missing { inserted on end split

Tags: equations, errors, split

I looked up and tried many previous posts on the matter with no success, any help would be great!

I am getting the error message : 
“latex missing } inserted” error message in equation"

```
  \begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
        a = max{(b(l{1}, vocab),\\
        b(l{2}, vocab),...\\
       ,b(l{n}, vocab))}
  \end{split}
  \end{equation*}
```

Comment: Each row in a `split` is contained in its own group, so you can't use a macro that takes arguments across rows.

Comment: @Skillmon Thank you! Is there any other way to write this equation on several lines?

Comment: You might want to use `\max` instead of `max`, the latter uses the wrong font for an operator. Also `\max` doesn't take any argument, so you can just drop the two braces. If you want to have braces in your output, you have to use `\{` and `\}` instead.

Comment: @Skillmon This solved the error and put an end to hours of work! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You might want to use `aligned` instead of `split`, also the things stated in my second comment remain true. Additionally, I'm not sure what you do mean with `vocab`, the way you put it it would be interpreted as `v*o*c*a*b` (so 5 factors), if this is a word, you might want to put a `\text` around them (provided by `amsmath`), or a `\mathrm`.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14,preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  a = \max\{(
    &b(l\{1\}, \text{vocab}), \\
    &b(l\{2\}, \text{vocab}), \dots, \\
    &b(l\{n\}, \text{vocab}))\}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think the traditional way of typesetting this is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 a = \max_{i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}}\{b(\ell_i, vocab)\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 a = \max_{1\le i\le n}\{b(\ell_i, vocab)\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

modulo the uncertainty what `vocab` really is.

Answer (score 2):

From the need of splitting this, I guess you're dealing with a two column document.

It's a common misunderstanding that `\max` takes an argument. It doesn't. Likewise for `\sum`, `\int`, `\log` and the other operators.

In your case it's better to use slightly bigger outer delimiters.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
a = \max\bigl(
  &b(l_{1}, \mathit{vocab}), \\
  &b(l_{2}, \mathit{vocab}), \\
  &\dots, \\
  &b(l_{n}, \mathit{vocab})\bigr)
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

I made a guess about `l{1}`: if it's not a subscript, then type simply `l1`. If you want braces, it should be `l\{1\}`.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in one of these ways, on two lines:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

 \begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
        a = \max\bigl( b(l_{1}, \mathrm{vocab}), b(l_{2},\mathrm{ vocab} & ), \\
        \dots, b(l_{n}, \mathrm{vocab} & )\bigr)
  \end{split}
  \end{equation*}

 \begin{equation*}
  \begin{multlined}
        a = \max\bigl( b(l_{1}, \mathrm{vocab}),b(l_{2},\mathrm{ vocab}), \\
        \dots, b(l_{n}, \mathrm{vocab})\bigr)
  \end{multlined}
  \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]